# Why is this inconsequential variable initialized within a for loop?

Tags: c

In the program I have pasted below, I was just wondering why the pointer "p" was initialized within the for loop? I am used to reading the conditions of a for loop as: starting from this value of a variable; until it reaches this value; increment it by this much. So it seems strange to have another variable that does not determine the ending condition and is not being incremented during each iteration in there at all.

I would have just put p=&a[0]; above the for loop and left the rest. Is this just a stylistic thing or are there differences in the way things are processed depending on where you initialize p? Is one way preferred over the other?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PRD(a) printf("%d", (a) )

int a[]={0, 1, 2, 3, 4};

int main()
{
     int i;
     int* p;

     for (p=&a[0], i=0; i<=4; i++) PRD(p[i]);

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because who ever coded that decided to put it there? :P

Comment: Easy enough to test. move the p=&a[0] outside of the loop and see if the output changes...

Comment: Yah, I can see the output is the same. I was just wondering if there was a benefit that I was unaware of - if there was any difference whatsoever.

Comment: Also, why not simply use `PRD(a[i])` instead of bothering with `p` at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be just a style thing. I would probably have also put the initialisation of `p` outside the `for` statement, since cramming everything in there makes the code harder to read. (Because the pattern of that `for` loop is different from what you might usually expect, an experienced programmer will have to stop, back up, and think about what's in there before it will make sense. I initially thought there were four clauses in the `for` control statements until I noticed that the first separator was a comma.)

Writing the code like this (instead of initialising `p` outside the loop) will have no effect on performance.

Comment: It's always better to write code that's easier for a human to read. A computer won't care either way.